# Link Delphi to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-xe4

I'm using Delphi XE4 & SQL server express 12, locally on C drive. I can link Delphi to Access DB via ADO comp. Problem is when I try linking SQL server db - it doesn't see my server/db. I'm not sure how I should specify my server name (USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS - name created by SQLserver) or my db name (C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLExpress\MSSQL\DATA\TestDB.Mdf). No passwords used. I tried via ADoTable (SQL SERVER Native Client 11.0 as well as Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server) and TSQLConnection.
(I've been using MS Access lately - out of touch with external db connection...)

Comment: Which edition of Delphi? Only the higher editions support client/server DBs.

Comment: That's the **version**, which is clearly stated in your question. But I want to know which **edition** you are using?

Comment: a valid connectionstring would be : Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=YOURDB;Data Source=YOURSERVER\YourInstance;

Comment: Also, for future reference, using tags that are completely unrelated to the question is very bad form. That just confuses people interested in those tags.

Comment: Ok, I'm new to this, am not exactly sure what I did wrong @David? Embarcadero® Delphi® XE4 Version 18.0.4854.59655. Not sure where to look for edition?

Comment: On the about window. Just below Product License Status the edition is displayed. For me it says *Professional*. <snark>You'd better hope for something better than that since professional developers don't need client/server access to databases.</snark> Having said all that, if the server is running on the same machine, then you may be able to access the data even with lesser editions. I'm hazy on that.

Comment: This one is Architect. Just testing to link Delphi to SQL server on this computer.

Comment: Then you are fine on that score.

Comment: @David:  Not quite true. ADO is supported in all SKUs (I have Pro, and have had since it was introduced. All Pro SKUs have supported ADO since Delphi 6 (Delphi 5 had a paid add-in that provided it you had to buy separately). XE4 Pro still includes the `TADO` components on the `dbGo` component palette.

Comment: @Ken So Pro can use ADO for client/server DB access? I must confess that I find this whole DB licensing insanely complex. Perhaps I should shup up and leave it to people that understand it.

Comment: @David: Yes. dbExpress (not dbGO) has the limitations on licensing. ADO works fine; I use it all the time for importing Excel and SQL Server data into our systems.

Comment: Which version of SQL Express did you install? -- There are 5 downloads, one of which is "SQL Server Express LocalDB" which means there is no service running.  That may be why Delphi can't "Browse" for the server - it isn't running.

Comment: Not sure where to check whish version I've got?

Comment: You can connect that SQL Server using another tool? SS Management Studio? And to what Server/db combination it's there?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the server information somehow, you can use a ConnectionString which is then used to build the connection. The connection string looks like this:

```
ConnString =
  'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;' +
  'User ID=%s;Password=%s;Data Source=%s;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;' +
  'Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;'+
  'Tag with column collation when possible=False';
```

Take a look at [this example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/ADOQuery_%28Delphi%29) uing ADOQuery.

And take a look at the documentation: [Connecting to Databases - Overview](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Connecting_to_Databases_-_Overview)

Comment: Thank you, @CloudyMarble. I don't know how to address SQL-server though, Delphi doesn't seem to "see" my server. Maybe my SQL-server setup is incorrect?

Comment: The SQL server should be accesable by ‘USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS’ or maybe ‘(local)\SQLEXPRESS’. If not, then SQL server is probably not running correctly or not corrctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on the TADOConnection component, you will have an option to Edit Connection String. This opens a dialog, with a button labelled Build...

Clicking this opens a wizard. Select "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" as the provider, and click Next. You are now offered a list of all the SQL Servers that are currently visible. If yours is not in this list then it is unavailable. Has the SQL Server service been started?

If it is in the list then follow the wizard through to build a valid connection string.

Comment: I have tried this with above Provider, as well as SQL Server Native Client 11.0, but no servers-list appeared. I tried with SQL server open / closed, without success. I'm not sure how to let Delphi "see" SQL-server.

Comment: It sounds to me that the problem liies with your SQL Server, not Delphi, as I can see dozens of SQL Server instances listed from within ourorganisation if I use the Build Connection String wizard.

Comment: @user2378627 You may need to enable the tcp/ip port 1433 using the Configuration Manager. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have to get connected to MSSQL Express with no regard to bitness (32/64). Your SQL Server Express have enabled the TCP/IP and/or Named Pipes connectivity instead of just Shared Memory?

To check, launch SQL Server Configuration Manager (don't know if it changed on 2012, but it's the name on 2008/2008r2) and look under ***SQL Server Network Configuration/Protocols for < your server instance >*** item (it'll have 2 of these on 64 bit systems, if my memory not failed me - my machine is 32bit, check on both).